# Using "IF Loop" to open PDF if closed

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file that will continuously check if a certain PDF is open, if not than it opens said PDF file.

I am new to batch file programming but have been able to create a batch file with "start" that opens the specific PDF. After doing some research I believe a for loop with use of a task-list might be able to get me what I need but do not really know how to implement it.

```
start AcroRd32.exe "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Folder1\PDF Forms\App.pdf "
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to happen if `App.pdf` is open in your browser or other/better PDF viewing program? Also this site helps you to fix a specific issue with your provided code, it doesn't provide you with code you haven't at least attempted to implement yourself.

Comment: Possible that PowerShell might be a better tool for this than batch on Windows

Comment: Could you please expand on that statement, @SamiBadawi?

Answer (score 0):

**UNTESTED**
This might work for you.  I think it will fail if the pdf is read only to the user.
**WARNING** Be very careful typing or copying `type nul>>"%filename%"`.  If you mess it up you can erase the contents of the file.  It must be double `>>`.  A single `>` will erase the contents.

```
set "fname=C:\Users\user1\Documents\Folder1\PDF Forms\App.pdf"

:infiniteloop

:: Check if the file is accessible, goto openfile if it is
(type nul>>"%fname%" && goto :openfile) >nul 2>nul

:: 1 second delay so the loop doesn't go crazy
timeout /t 1 >nul
goto :infiniteloop


:openfile

start AcroRd32.exe "%fname%"

:: Give it time to open before checking again
:: I chose 30 seconds
timeout /t 30>nul
goto :infiniteloop
```

This depends on the file being "locked" or whatever by the program that has it open.  On my computer, Adobe Reader does "lock" a PDF file, but Microsoft Edge does not.

Comment: `type nul>>"%fname%` might be a little risky to newbies. If OP accidently adds only one redirect, it will `nul` the file... maybe just highlight the risk.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `for` loop for this it would just create an extra process which is not needed.

```
@echo off
:start
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq App.pdf" | find /i "AcroRd32.exe"
if errorlevel 1 start AcroRd32.exe "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Folder1\PDF Forms\App.pdf"
timeout /t 10 >nul 2>&1
goto :start
```